# How to subtract a series from a dataframe with matching indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with a number of columns, and a `Series`. Both have the same `DateTimeIndex`.

I want to subtract each row's value in the `Series` from all the values in each row in the `DataFrame`

Here is my sample data:

```
dates   = pandas.date_range('20180101', periods=10)
stocks  = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'FB']
data    = numpy.random.randn(10,5)
prices  = pandas.DataFrame(index=dates, columns=stocks, data=data)
returns = prices.pct_change(1)
```

This gives me a `DataFrame` similar to the following

[image]

I then create my `Series`, which is the return of the basket of stocks

```
basket = returns.mean(axis=1)
```

This gives me a `Series` similar to the following

[image]

Now I want to subtract the basket returns from each stock's returns:

```
excess_ret = returns - basket
```

I am getting the following warning:

> ```
> RuntimeWarning: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str', sort order is
> undefined for incomparable objects
>   return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
> ```

This is the resulting `DataFrame`:

[image]

This *used* to work in `pandas-0.16.2`, but I am now using `pandas-0.22.0`, and it seems I am unable to subtract a `Series` from a `DataFrame` with matching `Indexes` now?

**Questions:**

- What is happening in this subtraction operation I am currently performing?
- How can I subtract  each row's value in the `Series` from all the values in each row in the `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html)with parameter `axis=0` for match index of `DataFrame` by index of `Series`:

> axis : {0, 1, 'index', 'columns'}
>
> For Series input, axis to match Series index on

```
excess_ret = returns.sub(basket, axis=0)
print (excess_ret)
                AAPL      GOOG      MSFT      AMZN        FB
2018-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-01-02 -1.833226 -0.110935  0.455586 -0.173553  1.662127
2018-01-03 -0.662713  1.737714 -1.295243  1.381853 -1.161611
2018-01-04  3.269817 -0.824819  0.377973 -0.788368 -2.034604
2018-01-05 -0.082528  1.814466  2.295359 -3.543489 -0.483808
2018-01-06  0.295950  2.978380  1.000856  1.346977 -5.622164
2018-01-07  1.988864 -2.316191  0.633370  1.043901 -1.349943
2018-01-08 -2.640122 -0.861669 -1.472634 -1.559951  6.534376
2018-01-09  8.062484 -1.712583 -2.497513 -0.807566 -3.044822
2018-01-10 -1.823915  0.370618 -0.883559  0.888679  1.448177
```

---

If want match by columns:

```
a = returns.mean(axis=0)
print (a)
AAPL    0.088224
GOOG   -1.301244
MSFT   -2.436290
AMZN   -1.009339
FB     -0.102484
dtype: float64

excess_ret = returns.sub(a, axis=1)
print (excess_ret)
                AAPL      GOOG       MSFT      AMZN        FB
2018-01-01       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-01-02 -1.353102  1.441870   5.759181  0.421661 -0.608508
2018-01-03 -0.434575 -0.969659   0.665239  0.823154  4.917633
2018-01-04  8.771575 -2.722012   0.409977 -2.113780 -1.164615
2018-01-05 -0.220083  0.213942   1.329937 -0.372537  0.037217
2018-01-06 -0.633686  6.371478 -14.157027 -0.831583  1.226992
2018-01-07 -2.363521  0.130848   1.743317 -1.381718 -1.929583
2018-01-08 -3.062185 -6.431137   0.438800  0.956752 -1.641623
2018-01-09 -0.450300  2.093572   2.965726 -0.617335  1.042234
2018-01-10 -0.254123 -0.128903   0.844849  3.115386 -1.879747
```

Comment: That was quick, thanks! Do you know what is happening in this subtraction operation I am currently performing? I'm pretty sure the way I'm trying to do it *used* to work, why does it no longer?

Comment: Additionally, I see in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) it says *"Equivalent to `dataframe - other`"*, but it seems it is not, as that operation yields a wildly different result!?