# Subtract from all columns in dataframe row by the value in a Series when indexes match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subtract 1 from all columns in the rows of a `DataFrame` that have a matching index in a `list`.

For example, if I have a DataFrame like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AMOS Admin': [1,1,0,0,2,2], 'MX Programs': [0,0,1,1,0,0], 'Material Management': [2,2,2,2,1,1]})

print(df)
       AMOS Admin  MX Programs  Material Management
0           1            0                    2
1           1            0                    2
2           0            1                    2
3           0            1                    2
4           2            0                    1
5           2            0                    1
```

I want to subtract 1 from all columns where index is in [2, 3] so that the end result is:

```
    AMOS Admin  MX Programs  Material Management
0           1            0                    2
1           1            0                    2
2          -1            0                    1
3          -1            0                    1
4           2            0                    1
5           2            0                    1
```

Having found no way to do this I created a Series:

```
sr = pd.Series([1,1], index=['2', '3'])
print(sr)
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```

However, applying the sub method as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117844/how-to-subtract-a-series-from-a-dataframe-with-matching-indexes) results in a DataFrame with all NaN and new rows at the bottom.

```
    AMOS Admin  MX Programs Material Management
0   NaN         NaN         NaN
1   NaN         NaN         NaN
2   NaN         NaN         NaN
3   NaN         NaN         NaN
4   NaN         NaN         NaN
5   NaN         NaN         NaN
2   NaN         NaN         NaN
3   NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks,
Juan

Answer (score 1):

Using `reindex` with you `sr` then subtract using `values`

```
df.loc[:]=df.values-sr.reindex(df.index,fill_value=0).values[:,None]
df
Out[1117]: 
   AMOS Admin  MX Programs  Material Management
0           1            0                    2
1           1            0                    2
2          -1            0                    1
3          -1            0                    1
4           2            0                    1
5           2            0                    1
```

Comment: Thank you Web-Ben. This helps a lot as well.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is that specific, why don't you just:

```
df.loc[[2, 3], :] = df.loc[[2, 3], :].subtract(1)
```

Comment: Hi Kartik, thank you. This gets to what I was trying ti accomplish but was unaware of the .substract()  being an option.